# How to insert new row after every 5 rows in Matlab?

Tags: frequency, matlab, time

I get time-domain measurement data from my oscilloscope (the data is an array of size 200000x2, the first column is for time and the second column is for the measurement). The sample time is 0.1 microseconds, but after every 5 rows, it changes to 0.2 microseconds. Now I'd like to perform an FFT analysis. I'll need to insert a new row every 5 rows to accomplish this.

Could someone please show me how to create a program that inserts a new row after every 5 rows and fills the rows with the average value of the adjacent rows in Matlab?

Comment: Use excel to do it.

Comment: What kind of wonky oscilloscope changes the sampling time during one scan?

Comment: [SO] or `matlabcentral` website might a be a better place to ask this.

Comment: When you talk about “rows”, do you mean samples? What does your data look like? I’d expect a 1D array (vector) with a value for each sample, but in that case it’s weird referring to “rows”, so maybe your data looks different.

Comment: Anyway, I would set up a second vector with the time for each sample, then use `interp1` to interpolate at uniformly spaced samples.

Comment: @ Andy aka, I have tried on excel but since the matrix is 20000X2, excel cant support it. thank you for the comment

Comment: @Cris Luengo the data is a 200000x2, the first column is for time and the second column is for the measurement

Comment: That’s fantastic. Then you can almost directly call `interp1`.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have data like the following:

```matlab
t = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9];
data = [t.', cos(t.')];
```

You can use [`interp1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) to resample the data at regular intervals as follows:

```matlab
dt = 0.1;           % desired sampling rate
t = t(1):dt:t(end); % desired sample locations
y = interp1(data(:,1), data(:,2), t);

plot(t, y, 'o-');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an easier way or if the below code is is correct for all sizes and shapes.

```matlab
function [mtxnew] = interleavedcopying(mtx, n1, n2)
if(nargin == 0)
  clc;
  % input data which has 20 rows and 3 columns
  mtx = rand(15, 1);
  n1 = 5;
  n2 = 6;
end

nn = size(mtx, 1);

% averaging currently works for single intermediate point only
assert(n2 == n1+1);

% this code works only for the "perfect" input case
assert(rem(nn, n1) == 0);

% make into groups of n1 rows
ii = floor([0 : nn-1]/n1)

% find the new locations where the data fits into
% nn/n1 is the reason why this code will work only for the "perfect" input
iinew = ii*n2 + repmat([1:n1], [1, nn/n1])

% create a big enough matrix filled with NaNs
nnnew = nn*n2/n1 -1;
mtxnew = NaN * zeros(nnnew, size(mtx, 2))

% copy the raw data
mtxnew(iinew, :) = mtx

% now fill in the avearge
kk = n2 : n2 : nnnew

mtxnew(kk, :) = ( mtxnew(kk-1, :) + mtxnew(kk+1, :) )/2;

plot(1:size(mtxnew, 1), mtxnew, '-x', kk, mtxnew(kk, :), 's');
end
```